# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug' error

Tags: java, android

I'm having this error above whenever i try to build an APK:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with arguments {--dex --num-threads=4 --multi-dex --main-dex-list C:\Users\admin\Desktop\FlagQuiz\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\maindexlist.txt --output C:\Users\admin\Desktop\FlagQuiz\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\1f\main C:\Users\admin\Desktop\FlagQuiz\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar}

This is my gradle build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.quiz"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
        }


        }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            'proguard-rules.pro'
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
//                checkRleaeseBuilds false
                abortOnError false
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {

    compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  <-- I commented it according to some solutions but it's didn't solve the problem
```

How i can solve this error, i've followed some solutions here and in some forums but nothing worked with me..

Thank you for any help!!

---

Gradle console:

```
Executing tasks: [:BaseGameUtils:assembleDebug, :app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

The setTestClassesDir(File) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the setTestClassesDirs(FileCollection) method instead.
The getTestClassesDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the getTestClassesDirs() method instead.
The ConfigurableReport.setDestination(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the method ConfigurableReport.setDestination(File) instead.
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

:BaseGameUtils:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:checkDebugManifest
:BaseGameUtils:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2540Library
:BaseGameUtils:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72540Library
:BaseGameUtils:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2540Library
:BaseGameUtils:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2540Library
:BaseGameUtils:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2540Library
:BaseGameUtils:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2540Library
:BaseGameUtils:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2540Library
:BaseGameUtils:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42540Library
:BaseGameUtils:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2540Library
:BaseGameUtils:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth1102Library
:BaseGameUtils:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase1102Library
:BaseGameUtils:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1102Library
:BaseGameUtils:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1102Library
:BaseGameUtils:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive1026Library
:BaseGameUtils:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames1026Library
:BaseGameUtils:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus1026Library
:BaseGameUtils:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1102Library
:BaseGameUtils:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics1102Library
:BaseGameUtils:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl1102Library
:BaseGameUtils:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon1102Library
:BaseGameUtils:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCore1102Library
:BaseGameUtils:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid1102Library
:BaseGameUtils:prepareDebugDependencies
:BaseGameUtils:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:BaseGameUtils:compileLint UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:copyDebugLint NO-SOURCE
:BaseGameUtils:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:javaPreCompileDebug
:BaseGameUtils:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:extractDebugAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:BaseGameUtils:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:BaseGameUtils:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:transformNativeLibsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:checkReleaseManifest
:BaseGameUtils:prepareReleaseDependencies
:BaseGameUtils:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:BaseGameUtils:copyReleaseLint NO-SOURCE
:BaseGameUtils:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:javaPreCompileRelease
:BaseGameUtils:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:BaseGameUtils:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:BaseGameUtils:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:transformNativeLibsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:BaseGameUtils:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2540Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72540Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72520Library
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportPaletteV72520Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2540Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2540Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2540Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2540Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2540Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42540Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2540Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsLite1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalyticsImpl1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthApiPhone1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAwareness1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCastFramework1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesClearcut1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGass1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesInstantapps1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlaces1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanager1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerApi1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerV4Impl1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVisionCommon1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAppindexing1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuth1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseConfig1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCore1102Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCrash1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabase1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabaseConnection1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDynamicLinks1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseMessaging1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorage1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorageCommon1104Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:javaPreCompileDebug
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders
:app:compileDebugShaders
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug

Running dex as a separate process.

To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has 1024 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to at least 2560 MB (based on the dexOptions.javaMaxHeapSize = 2g).
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2560M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with arguments {--dex --num-threads=4 --multi-dex --main-dex-list C:\Users\admin\Desktop\FlagQuiz\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\maindexlist.txt --output C:\Users\admin\Desktop\FlagQuiz\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\1f\main C:\Users\admin\Desktop\FlagQuiz\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar}

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 3s

154 actionable tasks: 102 executed, 52 up-to-date
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire Gradle Console output, rather than just one line. Most likely, the real problem appears higher in the output than this line.

Comment: I've edited the question, Thank you for your help!

Comment: I am not certain exactly what the problem is. However, your app is using 65 dependencies, which IMHO is insane. Adjust your `app/build.gradle` to only pull in the few things that you need. Right now, you seem to be trying to use *all* of Play Services and *all* of Firebase, and I sincerely hope you do not need most of that. With luck, by cleaning up your dependencies, your builds will work again.

Comment: lol, yes i'm using Google Play services and also Firebase for statistics and crashing report :)

Comment: Do i need to upgrade my pc's RAM? i only have 4Gbs

Comment: I would not develop for Android with less than 8GB. However, I do not know if that is the specific cause of your build problem.

Comment: I was working with my desktop pc with 8Gb of RAM without any problem, but now as i'm on vacation i'm using my laptop with 4Gb, and i'm keep getting this problems..So i think it's could have something with the PC's memory size..

Comment: That is certainly possible, particularly given your long list of dependencies. Besides, aren't you supposed to be on vacation? :-)